# AAPT2 error: check logs for details?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner in Android Studio ,I followed this tutorial https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/bottom-navigation-android-example/
and even when I downloaded it it returns this error [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AccLr.png)  and this is my file style .xml code  but the files shown in error I haven't used them  `

```
   <resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

`
 the only place where design navigation appears is in my activity_main.xml

```
           <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorNavIcon"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorNavText"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: show your style.xml file

Comment: Please clean your build. clean your project

Comment: I have edited the question ! I cleaned it and rebuilt it many times

Comment: Can you try updating your compile SDK version to P preview?

Comment: The same error !!

Answer (score 0):

The Android Asset Packaging Tool (AAPT) takes your application `res` files, such as the `AndroidManifest.xml` and the `xml` files for your Activities, and compiles them.

Sometimes it may occurs AAPT error, so try restart android studio after `Clean` and `Rebuild`